# Mistake during Oracle 11g PITR

Tags: oracle, rman

I tried using set time until.. and mis-typed the date.  Can anyone help me understand how to get my backups into a manageable state?

After the accidental recover, most of my backupset disappeared.

I recovered them and used 'catalog recovery area' .. and they're listed in 'list backupset'.  But something still isn't right.

When I do a PITR now, I get messages that my dbf files aren't available

and... the 'list backupset' seems to show backupsets.  But they are listed differently than the files which weren't included in the 'bad' recovery.

Gists with the error and the list of backupsets are here https://gist.github.com/akinsgre/5561254

Comment: A quick glance suggests you're stuffed, as there's only incremental backups and no full backups. One suggestion - copy the datafiles to another directory, then (I quote the documentation) "Record a datafile copy as a level 0 incremental backup in the RMAN repository, which enables you to use it as part of an incremental backup strategy.". Catalog the copies, then try the restore again. Have you checked what SCN the current datafiles are at?

Comment: Another thing, do a "LIST INCARNATION OF DATABASE yourdb" to see if there's been a resetlogs.

Comment: Phil:  I'm obviously missing something.  The backup set files show that they're full (or appear to me). But all the datafiles show incr.  I thought the backupset was supposed to include everything necessary for recovery?

Comment: And only one incarnation.. at least I did a full export before mucking around with this.

Comment: I thought they looked too small to be full - any idea hiw big the data is? I only had a quick skim read - on the iPhone from the pub :)

Comment: I really wish I was at the pub right now.. been at this for 11 hours so far.  database is about 1G   The tip fo r copying files worked.  I'm back to open.  Still trying to do a PITR to a previous copy so that I can get some data from a accidentally updated table

Comment: Awesome - keep me updated!

Comment: Just wondering, when using the syntax set until time "to_date('05/09/2013 06:10', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI')"; Isn't he missing the AM/PM indicator? :). Other option would be HH24:MI

Answer (score 0):

So after working through the info that Phil gave me.. and doing some research after the fact..

It appeared that the Set Until with a future date screwed things up by "removing, or de-cataloging my backups".  Even if that's possible (I don't know enough about Oracle to say) it wasn't the case.

What had happened was that my initial Full Backups were gone due to some poor data-retention.  So when I put a future date, it appeared like my PITR would work because it had a Full backup from a day ago.  However, I never did have a Full backup from a week ago.     I had taken one a couple months ago. but it had been deleted.

I'm using EM Console for my backups and haven't yet figured out how to tell it to do incrementals every day and fulls once a week.  I'll get there though.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Sorry for your data :-/